# jQuery - Filter a list based on 3 input field values

Tags: jquery

I have 3 input fields to check some sizes of products. Lets call it Width, Height, Length.

Then I have a master list of Widths, Heights, and Lengths where I want to filter.

When I enter numbers into the input fields, it should filter and show the closest matching jobs from an array or something similar. I want this to be jQuery and HTML only. Can you help? Im not sure where to start.

```html
Width <input type="text"><br>
Lendth <input type="text"><br>
Height <input type="text"><br>
<input type="submit">

<br/><br/>

PRODUCT LIST<br>
120 X 180 X 75 Company A $333<br>
127 X 80 X 175 Company A $715<br>
76 X 280 X 75 Company D $343<br>
220 X 110 X 175 Company E $133<br>
650 X 70 X 98 Company F $238<br>
150 X 10 X 77 Company S $342<br>
420 X 5 X 122 Company A $597<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check,

I hope following answer will help you

```js
// When page loading display all output elements ___
$(this).show();

// create fuunction for button click ___
function formSubmit(){
  var W = $('.widthInput').val(); // get width value from input
  var L = $('.lengthInput').val(); // get length value from input 
  var H = $('.heightInput').val(); // get height value from input 
  var V = W + ' X ' + L + ' X ' + H;  // get Width X Length X Height as a string
  var outputList = $('.outputList > p'); // get voutput element 
  
  // check wth each output element 
  outputList.each(function(){  
   var outPutVal = $(this).text(); // get each output item text
   
   // cross check "output item text" with input values and show hide the elements 
   if(outPutVal.includes(V)) { 
    outputList.hide();
    $(this).show();
   }
  });  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Width <input type="text" class="widthInput"><br>
Lendth <input type="text" class="lengthInput"><br>
Height <input type="text" class="heightInput"><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="formSubmit();">

<br/><br/>

PRODUCT LIST<br>
<div class="outputList">
<p>120 X 180 X 75 Company A $333</p>
<p>127 X 80 X 175 Company A $715</p>
<p>76 X 280 X 75 Company D $343</p>
<p>220 X 110 X 175 Company E $133</p>
<p>650 X 70 X 98 Company F $238</p>
<p>150 X 10 X 77 Company S $342</p>
<p>420 X 5 X 122 Company A $597</p>
</div>
```